Is there some error-case in this answer? for SICP 1.7
I'm a beginner with SICP.
For SICP 1.7, I assume this solution has some problem when '(improve guess x)' keeps returning different values compared to 'guess'.
But I can't find an error case for this solution.
Can you give me some advice or an error case?
Thank you.
#lang scheme
(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (if (good-enough? guess x)
      guess
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) x)))

(define (improve guess x)
  (average guess (/ x guess)))

(define (average x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (good-enough? guess x)
  (= guess (improve guess x)))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (sqrt x)
  (sqrt-iter 1.0 x))

I tried the following cases, but they did not fall into an infinite loop:
(sqrt 0.0000133415811023)
(sqrt 10230094109992910002)

Why do you expect an infinite loop?

Due to rounding errors in the average, please explain what "good enough" should be checking? Seems like you should check if the improved value is within some absolute distance from the guess, not exactly equal

https://sicp-solutions.net/post/sicp-solution-exercise-1-7/

@PeterWood I think the value of (improve guess x) converges to the value of the square root of x, but in some cases, (improve guess x) and the square root of x can never be exactly the same. This could lead to infinite recursion. I have already seen the content related to the answer you provided. I agree with this answer as well, but I wanted to understand the problem with the solution more precisely. I will take another look. Thank you.

@OneCricketeer I also believe that checking if the value is within an absolute distance rather than exactly the same is the correct approach. However, I asked the question to understand better the issues that arise when checking for exact equality. Thank you for your comment.

This post discusses binary floating point numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#588014

Aside: #lang scheme is long obsolete in Racket; should be using #lang racket (or better yet for SICP problems, install the sicp collection and use #lang sicp)

@Shawn I just installed #lang sicp, and if I hadn't known about this, I would have struggled more as the book progressed. Thank you so much.

You can't represent the square root of most numbers exactly, so if the algorithm converges it is always going to converge to an approximation.

This is why the good-enough? should check if the numbers are close rather than exactly equal.

@molbdnilo yes, the square-root of a prime number is always irrational, so the square root of most integers is the product of irrational numbers.
